# Apostrophe when using a noun to describe plural form of that noun?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, apostrophe

I want to say something like:

`You can almost empathize with the Robert Moses' of the world.`

Where `Robert Moses'` is being used to describe Robert Moses and other people like himself. Is the apostrophe needed? It's not really ownership, so should it be `Moseses?` That doesn't sound right either..

What would be the correct way to write this?

Another example without ending in `es`: `walker's of the world` or `walkers of the world`?  Would this be different than the `Moses` example?

Comment: I've seen several different "standards" proposed for this.  I think most authorities would just have you append the "es".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While apostrophes are used to describe plural forms, this usage is [limited to abbreviations, letters and words to avoid confusion](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/apostrophe.html#plurals).

In other contexts, `es` would be more straightforward.

Comment: Thanks so much!